# Windows or Android Tablet for developing an App that uses Videostreaming

Tags: android, windows, video-streaming, ms-media-foundation

I have seen that Tablet PCs or just tablets with Windows 10 are been seen more and more on the market, and I feel tempted to program for them since I already have quite some background with C#, besides Java, but since Video calling has some complexity, I'd like to ask first in which platform, Windows or Android, is it better/easier/comfortable/faster to develop an app that supports video calls? It won't be used for the broad public, like Skype, but rather within the internal network of a building. Probably videostreaming can be achieved faster and easier on Windows 10, but maybe things would get complicated if I need to make a videocall, let's say, between an Android Smartphone and such Windows Tablets. The latter is not completely necessary though.

Answer (score 0):

I've done video programming on Windows 10 and Android. For me Android was much easier than Windows. In Windows 10 you'll need to learn [Microsoft Media Foundation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/microsoft-media-foundation-sdk) which was a very steep learning curve for me personally.